# How to get form values from multiple child components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a large HTML Form and it has multiple fields in multiple components.

All these components are in a Parent Component.

How Can I submit a form and getting values from all child components?

```
<form>
  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
     <SameDay />
  </Col>
  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
     <International />
  </Col>
  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
     <OutBondTracking/>
  </Col>
  <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
     <FulfilmentOptions />
  </Col>
  <button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-primary mr-2"
    onClick={() => this.submitHandler()}
  >
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It depends. Are you implementing state at all?

Comment: FYI: you can use `onClick={this.submitHandler}` instead of `onClick={() => this.submitHandler()}`

Comment: Are you using and library to maintain state, like redux?

Comment: @sSDYes I am using Redux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass a handler function in the subcomponents(child components) that gets triggered when anything changes and updates the state in the parent component eg:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {} . // form data
    }

  }

  onChangeHandlerFn = (data) => {
    // update the state;
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  submitHandler = () => {
    // your handler function
     post your data from the state (data)
  }


   render() {
     return (
        <form>
          <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                       <SameDay />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                        <International onChangeHandlerFn={this.onChangeHandlerFn}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                        <OutBondTracking onChangeHandlerFn={this.onChangeHandlerFn} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
                        <FulfilmentOptions onChangeHandlerFn={this.onChangeHandlerFn} />
                    </Col>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary mr-2"  onClick= 
                 {this.submitHandler}>Submit</button>
       </form>
     );
   }
}
```

handler function onChangeHandlerFn={this.onChangeHandlerFn}, should be called if anything is changed in the child components, which intern updates the state of the parent component

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Even I have redux in my project but I prefer this way.

Comment: Hey I am new to React. I am having the same problem.Can u please elaborate the solution?@TarunNagpal @Joseph

Answer (score 2):

@Tarun, as you have mentioned you are using `redux` then you can create a `reducer` with `states` having all fields name like:

```
 const formState = {
    name: null,
    age: 4,
    address: null
};
```

for every `input` like `textfield, textarea, checkbox` attach a `onchange` event which changes the state of the formState by dispatching actions.

Comment: I know this is a good approach but it necessary extra lines of code as compared to "pass a handler function in the subcomponents".

What do you think ?

Comment: or you can dispact a single action when a submit button is clicked @TarunNagpal, but by using above approach you can implement validations while user is entering data.

Answer (score 1):

> Use React [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and named `input` fields.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.form = React.createRef(); // <------ Create a Ref
  }

  submitHandler = () => {
   const form = this.form.current
   alert(`sameday: ${form['sameday'].value}, international: ${form['international'].value}`)
  }

  render () {
     return (
        <form ref={this.form}> // <------ Hook the Ref
          <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
             <SameDay name='sameday' /> // <------ Pass 'name' prop
          </Col>
          <Col md={6} className="mb-3">
             <International name='international'/>
          </Col>
          <button onClick={this.submitHandler}>Submit</button>
        </form>
     );
   }
}
```

PS You have to attach the `name`s passed as props in your Input Field Components as an attribute to the `<input>` tag used in their respective code. Read more about form `name` attribute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp).

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-shtnxj